# comparision between undefined and complex number

Tags: calculus

I was asked the following question and asked to evaluate it: $\log(-8)$.
Do I answer that the answer will be a complex number and therefore no real answer exists? Is that true to say?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what range of answers are acceptable.  You are correct that there is no real $x$ such that $e^{x}=-8$.  The logarithm can be defined in the complex numbers and there are then solutions: $\ln 8 + (2k+1) \pi i$ for integral $k$.